# Cmake how to make header files automatically include their source files

Tags: hyperlink, header, cmake

I apologize if this has been answered, I've searched for some time and could not find a straight answer.

I'm used to windows visual c++ where I use a header file (`*.h`) for declaring classes and it's functions and a source file (`*.cpp`) where the actual class's functions are coded in detail. I am now working under Linux using Kdevelop which uses `cmake`. I've created some header files with classes in them and declared their functions and then coded the functions in their respective source files. Every time I try to build, I get errors that tells that `Class::function()` is an undefined reference. If I add the actual function in the header file, building works fine. So I am assuming that `cmake` is not linking correctly the respective source file for the header file. I was assuming that this would happen automatically, but I'm now guessing that this is not the case. How can I do that? For every header file I create, using the exact same name for the source file, have it all linked and build?

If this has been answered already, please post a link, if not, I would love a simple explanation. I understand there are many ways of doing this (`autoconf`, `make dep`, etc?) but for now I'm stuck with `cmake`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example CMakeLists.txt for a project named Test that links two source files into an executable named test.

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
project( Test )
add_executable( test test.cpp testlib.cpp )
```

if you want to add more source files just add them to the list.

Comment: Thank you that worked, but I guess there is no way to automate this for any newly added pair of foo.h & foo.cpp ?

Comment: There are two ways that this could be done.  The recommended method would be to get KDevelop to add the files to the source list as shown above.  It is also technically possible to use a cmake command like file( GLOB source_list *.cpp ) to generate a list of sources in a directory.  However, I only mention this to say that this is a bad idea.  If you do this you will have to remember to blow away you whole build directory every time you add a file, because cmake will not be able to tell that a new file has been added.

Comment: Sorry if this comes off preachy, but I am going to stand on my soapbox here for a minute.  IDEs in general do a horrible job of managing build systems.  Especially, when projects get large.  It really is worth it to learn a proper build system.  If I were in your situation, rather than spending a whole bunch of time trying to make KDevelop generate build files; I would learn how to use CMake.  It is no my favorite build system, but it is IMO one of the two or three "good ones".  It will pay dividends in the future.  I will step off the soap box now;-)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the mere existence of a `.cpp` file doesn't necessarily mean it will be linked in to your project when you build it. When you created a new `.cpp` file in Visual Studio, VS automatically added the `.cpp` file to your project, so you didn't have to think about it.

When using tools that don't hold your hand, you will have to add the relevant `.cpp` file to your project file manually. Consult the CMake documentation for how to do that. It looks like the [CMake Tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) may be of assistance here.